# Getting string values from JsonObject

Tags: json, servicestack

Suppose I have these JSON strings:

```
string s1 = "{\"foo\":\"wh\"o\"a\"}";
string s2 = "{\"foo\":{\"bar\":123}}";
```

I want to get the value of foo in string format, so out of s1 I want to get `"wh\"o\"a"` and out of s2 I want `"{\"bar\":123}"`. However if I do

```
JsonObject j = JsonObject.Parse(s1);
string foo = j.Get("foo");
```

foo contains `"wh"` from s1 and `"{"` from s2. How can I get raw string values of JSON fields using JsonObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first string is not valid JSON, it likely should be:

```
string s1 = "{\"foo\":\"wh\\\"o\\\"a\"}";
```

`JsonObject.Get` returns an escaped JSON string, if you want an un-escaped string you need to call `JsonObject.GetUnescaped`, e.g:

```
string s1 = "{\"foo\":\"wh\\\"o\\\"a\"}";
string s2 = "{\"foo\":{\"bar\":123}}";

JsonObject.Parse(s1).GetUnescaped("foo").Print(); //  wh\"o\"a
JsonObject.Parse(s2).GetUnescaped("foo").Print(); // {"bar":123}
```